# Merging of dataframes with different number of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have these two dataframes.

DF1:

[image]

DF2:

[image]

I want my output DF to be be DF1 along with the value of X1 from DF2. That is, this is how I want the output to look like:

[image]

I have tried using merge and join, but am unable to get this required output. The primary problem seems to be due to the fact that the ID in DF1 has multiple matches in DF2. The resulting dataframe I get has all the rows, somewhat like this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

(apologies for table images, I wasn't able to figure out how to create a table on the fly)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `match` to return the first hit in `DF2`.

```
DF1$X1  <- DF2$X1[match(DF1$ID, DF2$ID)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep unique values in terms of `ID` in the second data frame and then join:

```
library(tidyverse)
DF2 <- DF2 %>% 
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select(ID, X1)

res <- DF1 %>% 
  inner_join(DF2, by = "ID")

glimpse(res)
```